# PECL install failed

Tags: php, memcached, pear, pecl

after upgrading from PHP5.2.6 to php 5.3. it seams, I also have to reinstall the PHP memcache-module.
So I downloaded the newest version of memcache (3.0.6) and followed this documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.pear.php

```
pecl install memcache
```

Which results in the following error-message:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/memcache"
install failed
```

what's going on here? By the way: the server is not connected to the Internet, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?!

Comment: `the server is not connected to the Internet` - and how you want to install package? lol :)

Comment: @OZ_ the pack is still downloaded from the pecl website and placed on the servers local file system.

Comment: and who knows about that? Only you. In command `pecl install memcache` no any paths to the files of package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer my own question an for rising the intellectual horizon of @OZ_ and @martswite

an offline-installation of an pecl extension works like the following way:

1.) download the extension from http://pecl.php.net/packages.php

2.) there you get an .tgz file

3.) install the file:

```
 pear install memcache-3.0.6.tgz
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `pecl install memcached-3.0.8` and got `Failed to download pecl/memcached, version "3.0.8", latest release is version 2.2.0, stability "stable", use "channel://pecl.php.net/memcached-2.2.0" to install
install failed` (with stability changed to beta). So I manually downloaded the package and I installed it with `pear install memcache-3.0.8.tgz`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PECL modules are (by default, and most of the time) downloaded from a non-local repository. 
Therefore you will need some form of internet connection to download it.

Alternatively you can upload the pecl package from your machine to a location on the servers local file system and install it from there, or compile from source.

Comment: of course the pecl package is uploaded from the workstation to the server. but how tell pecl to realize an local installation?

Comment: @The Bndr - sorry, overlooked that bit, but you've got there yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

To me this error was caused due to php without support for ssl.
Enable openssl or recompile with openssl built int.
Check php support in a Linux host run

```
php -i | grep openssl
```

Should print a line with openssl if support enabled.