# PHP pecl and current finfo Version

Tags: php, mime-types, file-type, pecl

i need to determine the filetype of an file with php (5.3.7), no matter what filenameextension is used.

On Linux OS system i would use read the first Bytes from a file to find out the exact file type.

I think this is possible in PHP by using [`finfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)

The Point is: my Server is not connected to the Internet, so I have to download the `finfo` `PECL` extension manually.

All that i found was this website: http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo where the current `finfo` version is from from November 2006.

There is also an hint "his package has been superseded". But superseded by what?
If i take a look at this
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php there is no information where i found this package.

The only thing i found there is "This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. " Does it mean, that this extension is part of every default >=PHP 5.3.0 installation? But if i try to use `finfo` commands, i get an `Call to undefined function` which looks like `finfo` is not installed, right?!

//Edit: by the way: i'm working on Linux, PHP 5.3.7

Comment: I believe this "`This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0`" is a bit misleading, it's bundled by default but not enabled. Add this line `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` to your `php.ini` or `extension=fileinfo.so` for Linux

Comment: no, i'm not on windows. At my linux system, no file called *info*so exists

Comment: Oh Adnan, thank you for sharing this file... but, this project will go on production insight an internal company network. I'm not sure if i should use an file from "somewhere" / from an unknown dropbox account, you know?! Is there no official website?

Comment: Now this is very interesting, it seems that you've asked a similar question AND you've answered your own question later with the solution to solve **this** problem. Very interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099439/pecl-install-faildams

Comment: :-D, the difference is, that NOW I don't have the package to install, except the old one from 2006. The question is not: how tow install (this now i know) the question is: is there a newer package and where can i find it? sorry for confusing!

Comment: I don't think there's any newer version, I've checked our installation logs and it seems that the version I gave you is `1.0.4-2` so I think you're stuck with [this](http://pecl.php.net/get/Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz)

Comment: @Adnan I was on an completely wrong way. There exists an PHP package, which I have to install to get this functionality. But thank you so much for supporting me and the time you spend. :-) Greetings to the north!

Comment: i would like to know, why this question has an down-vote? This was an real question, where i searched the answer for hours. Maybe different users have an equal problem. Is it a problem if i answer my own question, if i found one? I think it's not the good way voting down a question without telling why....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I was on an wrong way for searching an new pecl file_info version. 
For Linux Systems there exits an PHP package, which contains that extension, like this:  `php5-fileinfo-5.3.6-75.1.x86_64.rpm` (depending on your Linux Distribution and PH Version)
To use fileinfo, you have install this package, like this:

`#rpm -ihv php5-fileinfo-5.3.6-75.1.x86_64.rpm`